# Get ID of featured image using "get_post_thumbnail_id(the_ID())" - without printing to screen?

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I'm using the code:

```
get_post_thumbnail_id(the_ID())
```

to get the ID of a post thumbnail image, but whenever I call this it outputs the ID to screen. I just want to get the value to use in another function, without it echoing anywhere.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `the_ID()` in this case, since it will *echo* the `ID`, use instead [`get_the_ID()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) to return it.

So please try this instead:

```
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() );
```

to  get the `ID` of a post thumbnail image.

The general rule is that `the_*()` functions will *echo* the output, but `get_*()` functions will *return* it. But  of course there are exceptions to every rule, so be careful ;-) If in doubt test it, consult the Codex or check out the source code.

Comment: I've just found this out in the last 10 minutes. Doh! I was completely ignorant of the fact that could have been the problem. Thanks for the explanation too.